# How to make content editable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a todo list and I want to have editable task so I gave contenteditable = "true" attribute to p tag which contains the task content but when I left click on it, it does not work but when I right click it works! I gave this attribute to heading and it works just fine but its not working on tasks( p tag).
so my question is how can I make tasks editable when I click on them?(not by right click I want left click)
here is my code, please first make a task buy clicking on + button

```js
const taskInput = $(".main__input");
const taskRow = $(".task-row");
const task = $("li");
let id = 0;
// adding task

const addTask = function() {
  const markup = `
  <li data-id=${id}>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="task__checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
      </div>
      <p class="task" contenteditable="true">${taskInput.val()}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-task btn-delete icon" data-id=${id}>
      <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </div>

  </li>  
  `;
  taskRow.append(markup);
  id++;
  taskInput.val("");
};
$(".btn-plus").on("click", function() {
  if (taskInput.val() !== "") addTask();
});
// remove element first solution
taskRow.on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
taskRow.on("change", ".task__checkbox", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".task").toggleClass("checked");
});

$(window).on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && taskInput.val() !== "") addTask();
});

taskRow.sortable();
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.todo {
  width: 40rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(122, 122, 122);
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgb(46, 89, 89);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.main__input {
  padding: 1.4rem;
  border: none;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(116, 116, 116);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(116, 116, 116); */
  width: 100%;
}

.main__input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
  color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


.icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(52, 81, 81);
}

.icon:active {
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
}

.task-row {
  display: flex;
}

.task-block {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

.task__checkbox {
  width: 10%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
}

.task__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.8rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
}

.task {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.4rem 1rem;
  border: 0.01px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo">
    <h1 class="heading" contenteditable="true">To-do list</h1>
    <div class="todo-body">
      <div class="row add-block">
        <div class="main">
          <input type="text" class="main__input" placeholder="A task you want to compelete">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-plus icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="row task-row"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the culprit: `taskRow.sortable();`- once that gets removed, it works fine with left button click as well. So likely that functionality has a `preventDefault` call or something, that prevents the event from performing its default action.

Comment: This behaviour seems to be caused by the `sortable` plugin you're using. Check its docs to find a way to prevent drag & drop on specific elements. `jQuery UI`'s plugins usually provide such customization.

Comment: @alisafaeyan You're welcome! Glad we managed to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) and I have mentioned in the comments, the behavior is caused by [`jQuery UI` Sortable Plugin](https://jqueryui.com/sortable).

The fix is fairly easy, we'll simply use the [`cancel`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) option of the `sortable` method to *prevent sorting if you start on elements matching the selector*. <sup>Source: [Sortable Widget - jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable)</sup>

We will pass the `p[conteneditable]` selector (or any other selector you see fit) to prevent dragging from the `p` tag that contains the todo text.

Here's a live demo:

```js
const taskInput = $(".main__input");
const taskRow = $(".task-row");
const task = $("li");
let id = 0;
// adding task

const addTask = function() {
  const markup = `
  <li data-id=${id}>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="task__checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
      </div>
      <p class="task" contenteditable="true">${taskInput.val()}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-task btn-delete icon" data-id=${id}>
      <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </div>

  </li>  
  `;
  taskRow.append(markup);
  id++;
  taskInput.val("");
};
$(".btn-plus").on("click", function() {
  if (taskInput.val() !== "") addTask();
});
// remove element first solution
taskRow.on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
taskRow.on("change", ".task__checkbox", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".task").toggleClass("checked");
});

$(window).on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && taskInput.val() !== "") addTask();
});

/** drag & drop is disabled on p tags having content attribute set. You still able to move the item around by dragging from elsewhere (from the delete button for example) */
taskRow.sortable({
  cancel: 'p[contenteditable=true]'
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.todo {
  width: 40rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(122, 122, 122);
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgb(46, 89, 89);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.main__input {
  padding: 1.4rem;
  border: none;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(116, 116, 116);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(116, 116, 116); */
  width: 100%;
}

.main__input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
  color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(52, 81, 81);
}

.icon:active {
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
}

.task-row {
  display: flex;
}

.task-block {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

.task__checkbox {
  width: 10%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
}

.task__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(37, 115, 115);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 1.8rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
}

.task {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.4rem 1rem;
  border: 0.01px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo">
  <h1 class="heading" contenteditable="true">To-do list</h1>
  <div class="todo-body">
    <div class="row add-block">
      <div class="main">
        <input type="text" class="main__input" placeholder="A task you want to compelete">
      </div>
      <div class="btn-plus icon">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="row task-row"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I also recommend looking at [`portlets`](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets) as they provide a better way (in my opinion) to introduce drag & drop into your elements.